# How to format date in Filter in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder, logstash-file

I am using Logstash to output JSON message to an API. I am reading logs from a log file. My configurations are working fine and it is also sending all the messages to the API. Following is the sample log file:

**Log File:**

```
2014 Jun 01 18:57:34:158 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300009 BW Plugins: version 5.10.0, build V48, 2012-6-3 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:34:162 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300010 XML Support: TIBCOXML Version 5.51.500.003 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:34:162 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300011 Java version: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 20.5-b03 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:34:162 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300012 OS version: i386 Linux 3.11.0-12-generic 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:41:018 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100118 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:41:027 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100206 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:41:408 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Info [BW-Core] BWENGINE-300013 Tibrv string encoding: ISO8859-1 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:408 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100118 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:408 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100206 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:555 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100118 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:555 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100206 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:557 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100118 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:557 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100206 
2014 Jun 01 18:57:42:595 GMT +5 BW.Customer_01_001_009-Process_Archive Warn [BW_Core]  Duplicate message map entry for BW-HTTP-100118
```

I am using grok pattern to parse this log file, Following is my sample configuration file:

**Config File:**

```
filter {
        if [type] == "bw5applog" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "(?<log_timestamp>%{YEAR}\s%{MONTH}\s%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME}:\d{3})\s(?<log_Timezone>%{DATA}\s%{DATA})\s(?<log_MessageTitle>%{DATA})(?<MessageType>%{LOGLEVEL})%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}" ]
            add_tag => [ "grokked" ]        
        }
        mutate {
          gsub => [
             "TimeStamp", "\s", "T",
             "TimeStamp", ",", "."
           ]
        }
        if !( "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] ) {
            grok{
                    match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:StackTrace}" ]
                    add_tag => [ "grokked" ]    
                }
            date {
                    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
                    target => "TimeStamp"
                    timezone => "UTC"
                }
        }
     }
 }
```

I am able to parse the complete log entry according to my requirement, But I want to format the date.

**Problem Statement:**

Currently I am getting date in the following format from the parsed log entries:

```
log_timestamp:  2014·May·28·12:07:35:927
```

But the format in which my API is expecting the date is as below:

**Expected Output:**

```
log_timestamp:  2014-05-28T12:07:35:927
```

How can I achieve that by using the above mentioned filter configurations, I tried doing something with the following configurations but I wasn't able to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the date filter on the wrong field. Instead of `timestamp`, you have to apply it on the `log_timestamp` field, which contains the date you want to parse:

```
date {
        match => [ "log_timestamp", "yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
        target => "log_timestamp"
        timezone => "UTC"
}
```

In addition, the mutate filter is useless since it is applied on a field which does not exist (`Timestamp`).